# equation of a line perpendicular to the line

Tags: geometry

Given the points $A (11,19)$ and $B (6,9)$. Find the equation of a line perpendicular to the line $[AB]$ through the point $O (0,0)$. Would be great for some help thanks!

Comment: Start by finding the gradient of $AB$. What do you know about the gradients of perpendicular lines?

Comment: Hi i did the equation of AB is y=2x-3

Comment: Right, $AB$ has gradient $2$, so what is the gradient of a line perpendicular to $AB$?

Comment: -2? is it? Thanks sorry new to maths.

Comment: It's the negative reciprocal of the gradient of $AB$, i.e. $-1/2$.

Comment: @EoinDavidson I would suggest reading introductory books such as New Syllabus Mathematics by Oxford University Press to build a foundation in key concepts of Elementary Mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient $m$ of the line passing through $A$ and $B$ is the ratio of the difference in the $y$ coordinates to the $x$ coordinates. Hence $m=\frac{19-9}{11-6} =2.$ The product of the gradients of $2$ lines that are perpendicular to each other is $-1.$ So, the gradient of all lines perpendicular to the line passing through $AB$ is $-\frac{1}{2}.$ The equation you get now is $y=-\frac{1}{2}x+c$ where $c$ is the $y$ intercept. Since the line passes through the origin, $c=0$. Thus, the equation is $$y=-\frac{1}{2}x$$

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the dot product: if $M(x,y)$ is a point of the perpendicular, you have $\;\overrightarrow{OA}\cdot\overrightarrow{OM}=\overrightarrow{OB}\cdot\overrightarrow{OM}$, i.e.
$$11x+19y=6x+9y\iff 5x+10y=0\iff x+2y=0.$$